# Getting Jscript Compilation Error in reactjs app

Tags: reactjs

I am a beginner in reactjs. I am trying create my firs app that just log string to console browser but when I start, it gives jscript compilation error.
Please help me.
Thanks.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const element = <h1>Hello World</h1>;
console.log(element);
```

Comment: this is your complete code ?

Comment: What error you get? How do you run the code?

Comment: Error: "  Microsoft Jscript compilation error"

Comment: For running the app i use continue debug shortcut(F5).

Answer (score 0):

okay do it like this

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const Element = () => {
  console.log('First Render')
  return <h1>Hello World</h1>;
}
ReactDOM.render(Element, document.getElementById('root'))
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks but same as before.

Comment: How? I just create a react project using npm  and i remove files in src folder then create index.js and put above code in it.

Comment: why did you remove these files ?

Comment: I watched a tutorial which deleted that files. do think it causes problem?

Comment: yes maybe, just use create-react-app and you should be fine